# Dynamic PARTITION for MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, partition

I'm trying to do dynamic split by partitions for my `test` table, which has 2 partitions p0 and p1 before starting this script:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS part_splitting;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE part_splitting()
BEGIN

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MIN(createdOn), "%Y-%m-%d") INTO @s FROM test;
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MAX(createdOn), "%Y-%m-%d") + INTERVAL 1 MONTH INTO @e FROM test;
    SET @part_init := CONCAT( `ALTER TABLE test
    PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(createdOn) (
     PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (`,@s,`)
    )`);
  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @part_init;
  EXECUTE stmt1;

  WHILE @s < @e DO
    SELECT CONCAT('p', DATE_FORMAT(@s,'%y/%m/%d')) INTO title

    SET @part_adding := CONCAT(`ALTER TABLE test ADD PARTITION (PARTITION `,title,` VALUES LESS THAN(`,DATE_FORMAT(@s,'%y/%m/%d'),`))`);
    PREPARE stmt2 FROM @part_adding;
    EXECUTE stmt2;
    
    SET @s = @s + INTERVAL 1 day;
  END WHILE;
END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL part_splitting();
```

Currently, I have this error after execution:

```
SQL Error [1054] [42S22]: Unknown column 'ALTER TABLE test
    PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(createdOn) (
     PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (' in 'field list'
  Unknown column 'ALTER TABLE test
    PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(createdOn) (
     PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (' in 'field list'
  Unknown column 'ALTER TABLE test
    PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(createdOn) (
     PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (' in 'field list'
```

The key idea here create partitions dynamically every week by SQL event and split by days starting from min day in the table and end last date plus 1 month ahead

Does anybody have some ideas here?
Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE:**

***KUDOS*** to **@Bill Karwin** for the answers - really cool guy!!

So finally I have this working syntaxis:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS part_splitting;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE part_splitting()
BEGIN

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MIN(createdOn), "%Y-%m-%d") INTO @s FROM test;
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MAX(createdOn), "%Y-%m-%d") + INTERVAL 1 MONTH INTO @e FROM test;
    SET @part_init := CONCAT( 'ALTER TABLE test
    PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(createdOn) (
     PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (',QUOTE(@s),'),
     PARTITION pMax VALUES LESS THAN(MAXVALUE)
    )');
  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @part_init;
  EXECUTE stmt1;

  WHILE @s < @e DO
    SET @s = @s + INTERVAL 1 day;
    SELECT CONCAT('p', DATE_FORMAT(@s,"%Y%m%d")) INTO @title;

    SET @part_adding := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE test ADD PARTITION ( PARTITION ',@title,' VALUES LESS THAN (',QUOTE(@s),') );');
    PREPARE stmt2 FROM @part_adding;
    EXECUTE stmt2;
  END WHILE;

END 
$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL part_splitting();
```

**BUT:**

Looks like this approach for periodically running and adding new PARTITIONs dynamically doesn't work because we faced with the error:
`"Error Code: 1493. VALUES LESS THAN value must be strictly increasing for each partition`
that comes from the situation when some PARTITIONs were created before.

At the current moment, I don't know how I could skip these steps in the loop. Looks like we could use `...REORGANIZE PARTITION pMax...` every time but for this, we need to know the last date condition before `pMax`, that was created on the previous running. (but it's another story I guess...)

Comment: I am not sure if this is how partition work. You don't want to alter the partitioning every week. You set it to partition by week upfront with the amount of partitions equivalent to your amount of servers. `PARTITION BY HASH(CONCAT(YEAR(your_date), WEEK(your_date)))`

Comment: When it comes to distribution of data, have a look at Ketama algorithm which provides consistency across your distributed keys. Also have a look at this [MongoDB sharding guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-choose-a-shard-key/#std-label-sharding-shard-key-selection), because it's more or less equivalent, in case you are more familiar with MongoDB.

Comment: @DanielW. Yep It's not a regular case for partitions. Be we really want to repartition every week (on the weekend) by day and add some new partitions for the feature based on the current dates in the table. Another job will truncate the table time from time - so no need to keep an empty chapter, and on other hand, we need some new for new days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay the reason for the error is that you're using back-ticks when you should use straight single-quotes.

```
SET @part_init := CONCAT( `ALTER TABLE...
                          ^
```

This makes your whole `ALTER TABLE...` string interpreted as an SQL identifier, not a string. So the parser is trying to find a table or column whose name matches that string, and of course it can't.

Besides that issue, you'll hit other issues as you develop this.

```
CONCAT( 'ALTER TABLE test
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(createdOn) (
 PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (',@s,'))')
                               ^      ^
```

The value of `@s` is a date, right? But the SQL you're formatting won't have quotes around the date. So it'll end up being like this:

```
...VALUES LESS THAN(2021-12-21)
```

This isn't an error, but it won't do what you think. It'll evaluate the arithmetic expression 2021 minus 12 minus 21, which returns 1988.

You need to format dates with quotes like this:

```
...VALUES LESS THAN('2021-12-21')
```

An easy way to do that is like this:

```
CONCAT( 'ALTER TABLE test
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(createdOn) (
 PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (',QUOTE(@s),'))')
```

There are still other problems.

Your initial ALTER TABLE won't work unless you have truncated the table to zero rows before you do it, because by definition the single partition only stores values less than your minimum value. So there's no partition for the other existing rows with data. Did you try this?

Adding partitions one by one is going to result in at least dozens of ALTER TABLE statements, if not hundreds. It'll take too long to do that, and it's not necessary. You should repartition the whole table in one ALTER TABLE statement.

You should learn how to use DROP PARTITION and REORGANIZE PARTITION. I'll leave this to you to look up in the manual.

Finally, partitioning on a column like `createdOn`, I would ask if that column is part of every primary key or unique key in the table. This is a requirement for the partitioning column. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html

---

Re comments:

I tested this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE part_splitting()
BEGIN

    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MIN(createdOn), "%Y-%m-%d") INTO @s FROM test;
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MAX(createdOn), "%Y-%m-%d") + INTERVAL 1 MONTH INTO @e FROM test;
    SET @partition_sql = CONCAT( 'ALTER TABLE test
    PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(createdOn) (
     PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (',QUOTE(@s),')');

    WHILE @s < @e DO
      SET @s = @s + INTERVAL 1 day;
      SET @partition_sql = CONCAT(@partition_sql, ',
     PARTITION p', DATE_FORMAT(@s,"%Y%m%d"), ' VALUES LESS THAN (',QUOTE(@s),')');
    END WHILE;

    SET @partition_sql = CONCAT(@partition_sql, ', 
     PARTITION pMax VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
    );');

    SELECT @partition_sql;

END 
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Output:

```
ALTER TABLE test
    PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(createdOn) (
     PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-12-21'), 
     PARTITION p20211222 VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-12-22'), 
     PARTITION p20211223 VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-12-23'), 
     ...one for each day...
     PARTITION p20220121 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-01-21'),
     PARTITION pMax VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
    );
```

I have only output the ALTER TABLE statement, but you can PREPARE & EXECUTE it instead. The point is that the loop appends more partition clauses so the whole ALTER TABLE is done in one step instead of one ALTER TABLE per partition in each loop iteration.

Comment: You post something, I learn something, isn't that nice? Looking forward to buy your book 

Comment: Thanks so much @Bill Karwin!!!
Yep createdOn is part of Primary key.
And regarding to this part `...So there's no partition for the other existing rows with data. ...` table has some partitioning before this changes. (try to do it manually before), and yes the first version was with two partitions at the start but for this example, I've remove the second partition because thought that maybe this easy for debug

Comment: Regarding to this part: `... Adding partitions one by one is going to result in at least dozens of ALTER TABLE statements, if not hundreds. It'll take too long to do that, and it's not necessary. You should repartition the whole table in one ALTER TABLE statement....` Still don't know how do it in the WHILE DO loop... DO you have some examples?

Comment: You have a reputation score of 3000+ but you don't know how to append a string like `", PARTITION pN VALUES LESS THAN (...)"` in a loop?

Comment: :-) @Bill Karwin, pardon for the wrong wording. The question was mostly about how can I organize this part `...the whole table in one ALTER TABLE statement` something like this:
```ALTER TABLE test PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(createdOn) (
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (@s),
  WHILE @s < @e DO
                SET @s = @s + INTERVAL 1 day;
   PARTITION pN VALUES LESS THAN (QUOTE(@s))
  END
   PARTITION pMax VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
     );```
And then run it one time. But as I know we can't split PARTITION expression and inject at the middle some WHILE or other loop block.

Comment: And pardon again for the mess in the comment. 
And the question that I still have is how can I organized this loop for one iteration running with a dynamic butch of the PARTITION rows inside for periodically running in the MySQL event. It was the original idea of this decision, but I couldn't resolve it